# Debugging outline box 2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In box2d you can turn on the outline of the shape to debug you do this with

```
m_debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```

And it is called debug draw

Well I have a set of distance joint that I am trying to debug and was wondering if there was a function just like dubug draw but for distance joints.  I am currently working on a blob made up of many nodes all connected by spring like distance joints and to debug it would help if I could see where the joints are... Any help is much appreciated thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m_debugDraw->SetFlags(b2Draw::e_jointBit);
```

Should show the joints, I use a combo in my project to show everything like this:

```
uint32 flags = 0;
flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;
debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```

found that info at http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21311